# SQL Loader line endings

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have a data file that is in Windows format, and would like to load it in to Oracle with sqlldr. Unfortunately the Unix version doesn't intelligently detect with Windows format so I have a load of records with \r in them. Strangely, the Windows version would intelligently detect it.

Is there a parameter I can use in the control file to "switch on" auto detection? I don't want to assume the file will always be in Windows format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a quick note on UNIX

unix has a utility - dos2unix (sometimes called dos2ux)  that will change carriage control on files from Windows to UNIX. It is a one line command.

There is no option in sqlldr ctl files for carriage control other than DELIMITED BY.  The 'DELIMITED BY' clause in the control file lets you specify a single character, not two. Windows text files have two characters.

Not what you wanted hear. I'm sure.

Comment: Thanks. You are right it's not what I wanted to hear. I will have to live with dos2unix.